# looping through an array passed as parameter form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have passed multiple checkbox value as an array to rails controller where i want to loop through this passed array and return data to the view .

I am using Angularjs http.get to pass values

```
$scope.selection=[];
   $scope.getresultbyfood = function(dataname){

     var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(dataname);
     if (idx > -1) {

       $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
     }

     else 
     {
        $scope.selection.push(dataname);
     }

    $http.get('./pgresultsbyfood.json?food_type[]=' + $scope.selection).success(function(data){
     $scope.resultdata = data; 
     $scope.filteredPg = $scope.resultdata; 
    });     
    }
```

here in $scope.selection i am passing multiple checkbox values .
where in controller

```
def pgresultbyfoodtype
   food_types =  params[:food_type]
    i = 0

    food_types.each do |food_type|
         @pgresults = SearchResult.where(:food_type => food_type)
     end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @pgresults }
  end
```

but here in @pgresults i am getting no value.
in my log it is showing like

```
Started GET "/pgresultsbyfood.json?food_type[]=North-Indian,Both" for ::1 at 2016-01-23 21:14:16 +0530
Processing by ResultController#pgresultbyfoodtype as JSON
  Parameters: {"food_type"=>["North-Indian,Both"]}
  [1m[36mSearchResult Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `search_results`.* FROM `search_results` WHERE `search_results`.`food_type` = 'North-Indian,Both'[0m
Completed 200 OK in 0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, if you insist on passing an array in the query string, you'll have to do it like this:

```
param_name[]=a&param_name[]=b&param_name[]=c
```

Comment: if u see i am passing as food_type[]=' + $scope.selection,is this wrong.

Comment: Try:
`$http({
    url:  'pgresultsbyfood.json',
    method: "GET",
    params: { "food_type[]": $scope.selection }
 })`

Comment: i have tried this now i am able to loop through but no data is coming in result.